# Was Ezra believed to be Moshiach?

Tags: messiah, messianic-redemption

When the second Beis Hamikdash was being rebuilt, didnt the people think that this is the final redemption? And if so, they wouldve thought thay mashicach had arrived, so did anyone think that Ezra  was Moshiach ben David?

Comment: Ezra was a Kohen, so he couldn't be the Mashiach.

Comment: Nechemiah would have been a better candidate, as according to an opinion in Sanhedrin 38a, he was actually Zerubavel (a descendant of the Kings of Judah).

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10341/759